# Supabase auth.signUp() doesn't return data, only shows error in response

Tags: vuejs3, supabase

Thought I would take supabase for a spin over the holidays, simple to setup but I have hit a snag with email authentication.

I copy pasted the `signUp()` block from [the docs][1], but I'm unable to log out data on signup success. I am able to log the errors without effort when for instance, I try to signup with an existing email. I have validated that the registration data is being recorded in supabase accurately. I also checked the network tab & can see the access token and response there, but not from a console.log.

Hoping that there is something minor I've been overlooking, should I be checking for a session after signup?

I'm using supabase v2.0 & vuejs3/vite with the options API & pinia as my store

Here is the relevant code:

**RegistrationView.vue**

```
  methods: {
    async handleRegistration() {
      const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        options: {
          data: {
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            phone: this.phone,
          },
        },
      });
      if (error) {
        console.log({ error });
      }
      if (data) {
        console.log({ data });
      }
    },
  },
```

**Solved**: TLDR;

Don't destruct `data` from signup(), descruct `error`, `user` & `session` instead.

i.e.

```
const { error, session, user } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
  .
  .
  . 
})
```

Comment: What error are you seeing in the console?

Comment: I triggered an error manually just to sanity check the vars were connected correctly. I registered with an existing user's email and received a 400 User already registered.

Comment: Okay, I think I jumped ahead. What is the problem here? Everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: I am unable to log out data from the response.

Comment: So when you signUp a user, both error and data are null?

Comment: This is what the response from `signUp()` looks like. There will always be either data or error returned. https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/blob/master/src/lib/types.ts#L53 

What you are looking for can be found in `data.session` after a successful signUp. If you have email confirmation turned on though, you will not receive a session until you confirm the email. https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup

Comment: If I destructure `user` & `session` from `await signup` I receive the info as expected. Thanks for the guidance, if you post your comment as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Logging data should return something, but it is null.  It's [poor documentation] as they show destructuring to data & error
 (https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-signup)  Thank you @sirramongabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signUp()` will always return either data or error, so you should always see one or the other in your console.

What you are looking for should be contained inside `data.session` and `data.user`.

Comment: Any logging of the data object does not work.